# pandas : padding with 0 a rolling window

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe with some cumulated values over time, and I want to get back the daily values. Moreover, the cumulated sum is done separately for various locations.

```
    location    date    cum_sum
0   A   2020-01-01  15.0
1   A   2020-01-02  18.0
2   A   2020-01-03  23.0
3   B   2020-01-01  8.0
4   B   2020-01-02  16.0
5   B   2020-01-03  34.0
```

I came up with the following solution :

```
def pair_diff(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x[0]
    else :
        return x[-1] - x[-2]

df.groupby("location")["cum_sum"].expanding().apply(pair_diff, raw = True)
```

I feel that my solution is not optimal, because for large time span, the expanding window will be very large and inefficient. Using `rolling` instead of  `expanding` does not work because I get `NaN` instead of single value at the beginning of a group. However, this could be easily solved if `rolling` enables to pad with 0 on window without enough data.

Any idea ?

Comment: what is the expected answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, what you are after is actually the difference between cum_sums  by group (location). In this case, I do not understand why you want to mix this up with the cum_sum value for the first date for each location. I think it would be better to separate cum_sums from their differences. I suggest this. Calling your dataframe `dte`, which is

```
  location        date  cum_sum
0        A  2020-01-01     15.0
1        A  2020-01-02     18.0
2        A  2020-01-03     23.0
3        B  2020-01-01      8.0
4        B  2020-01-02     16.0
5        B  2020-01-03     34.0
```

you can perform the calculation as:

```
dte.sort_values(['location', 'date'], inplace=True)
dte['diffs'] = dte.groupby(['location'])['cum_sum'].transform(lambda x: x.diff()) 
dte.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

which gives:

```
 location        date  cum_sum  diffs
0        A  2020-01-01     15.0    NaN
1        A  2020-01-02     18.0    3.0
2        A  2020-01-03     23.0    5.0
3        B  2020-01-01      8.0    NaN
4        B  2020-01-02     16.0    8.0
5        B  2020-01-03     34.0   18.0
```

This way, you also keep the original data.

**EDIT**
However, if you absolutely want the cumsum value:

```
dte['diffs'] = dte.apply(lambda row: row['cum_sum'] if np.isnan(row['diffs']) else row['diffs'],axis=1)
```

which gives

```
 location        date  cum_sum  diffs
0        A  2020-01-01     15.0   15.0
1        A  2020-01-02     18.0    3.0
2        A  2020-01-03     23.0    5.0
3        B  2020-01-01      8.0    8.0
4        B  2020-01-02     16.0    8.0
5        B  2020-01-03     34.0   18.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need a value for the 1st date, and not NaN. Since my data is cumulative, the cumulated value for the first day is actually the daily value.

Comment: Made an edit but not sure you're better off than with your loop. Depends on the size of your data...maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I post there the answer that another user gave, and that was deleted shortly after (why ?) :

```
df.groupby("location")["cum_sum"].diff().fillna(df["cum_sum"])
```

This is much shorter and elegant that my previous solution. And the first date is filled with the first cumulated value as I wanted (cumulated value is daily value at the beginning of each serie).